# Is there a way to use Vim keybindings in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google colaboratory is an amazing tool and the only thing that keeps me from using it more often is the absence of vim keybindings. Is there a way to enable it just like its possible to do for jupyter notebooks and jupyter lab?

Answer (score 30):

It's now available in google colab by default.
You can select Vim keybindings from Tools > Settings > Editor, or by typing Ctrl+M H

Comment: Just wanted to add a followup to that answer (that should now be the only accepted one btw) : This feature is now enabled on any Colab notebook. No need for the "experimental" editor.

Comment: Yes, but that is too bad, I think, you don't get to use norm and many other commands, there should be someplace to put vim config, so that we could add a script to do so in our first cell

Answer (score 10):

Here is a little hack to enable Vim mode via the JavaScript console. Annoyingly, it needs to be re-run each time a cell is executed, so I've bound `ctrl/cmd-enter` and `shift-enter` to do just that:

```
function enable_vim() { document.querySelectorAll(".CodeMirror").forEach(function (e) { e.CodeMirror.setOption("vimMode", true); }); }
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.metaKey || e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) setTimeout(enable_vim, 1000 * i);
  }
});
enable_vim();
```

Just be careful to be in *normal mode* (not in *input mode*) when running a cell. Otherwise Vim mode will be permanently disabled for that cell and one needs to reload the entire web app to re-enable it.

Comment: Thanks! When will they add this as a setting for colaboratory? You're a real life saver for me. ;)

Comment: This actually seems like a pretty easy task for a Chrome Plugin. When active, check websites for the existence of a .CodeMirror class and enable vimMode on them all by default?

Comment: Brain storming my own comments again. Surely there's an event emitted whenever a user clicks on a Jupyter code window? The above script can be modified instead to just add a listener for that event and enable vimMode any time the cell is clicked.

Answer (score 6):

Due to previous conversation in this posting, I've published `autovim` to the Chrome extension store. It works perfectly as far as I have found with permanently visible `CodeMirror` elements, but is still flaky with `CodeMirror` elements that hide and show like those for Markdown in Jupyter.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autovim/licohjbphilmljmjonhiifkldfahnmja

You can contribute here if you desire:

https://github.com/thomcom/autovim

Comment: Could you perhaps publish the same extension for Firefox too ?

Answer (score 1):

Not right now; feel free to file an issue at https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools.